# How effective is "spider-sense" against different forms of teleportation?

Tags: comics, spider-man, marvel, teleportation

In a nutshell, how well does spider-sense work against short range teleportation (like Nightcrawler) and how well against long range teleportation (like The Hood). I'm curious at what point, if at all, is Spider-Man alerted to someone teleporting near to him. Can he be 'jumped in' on without being alerted by his spider-sense more easily than he could be snuck up on in a conventional sense?

Anyone know if there's a 616 precedent for this, or if it's all over the map depending on who was writing at the time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't read the issues myself, but I know that Spider-Man and Kurt have squared off on a few occasions. The comments I've read have said that Kurt has the upper hand as Spidey can't pinpoint where the danger is coming from.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The Spot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_%28comics%29) is one of Spider-Man's most difficult adversaries.  While his abilities aren't clearly defined as "Teleportation" they do function in almost the same way as [Nightcrawler's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Wagner_%28comics%29#Powers_and_abilities)  They both open portals to alternate dimensions then transit through said portal to an exit point at a different location.  The main difference between the two is the level of control over those portals.  While Nightcrawler teleports his entire body and a certain amount of the surrounding area, The Spot can move, all or portions of his body through his "spots".  Spider-Man's "[Spider Sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man%27s_powers_and_equipment#Spider-sense)" can not predict attacks from other dimensions, so if Nightcrawler where to attack him it would be the same difficulty as fighting The Spot.

[image: Wham!!]

Comment: That’s a great picture. Kind of sums up Spider-Man in one shot.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, sounds like it's the same no matter what the distance is.  Thank you sir.